# What's the point of 'default=True' in BooleanField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple question: in my model, I am defining the structure for one of my tables; however, I want to set up a default value for the `Booleanfield`: `own`, but it does not seem to be working properly. Here is my code in the model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    own = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When I `desc` my table in mysql, this is what I get (*note that own has default Null*):

[image]

Also, when I try to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO `counters_books` (`title`) VALUES ('My Brain is Open')
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'own' doesn't have a default value
```

P.S. I understand that by using `NullBooleanField` I will be able to solve the problem; however, what's the point of `default` if I cannot insert a row unless I had to specify a value for that field?

Comment: Did you add the default after creating the database/tables?

Comment: @mipadi: I'm not sure what that means; but there was no `Books` table before I ran `python manage.py syncdb`!

Comment: The right test is `book = Book('1984'); book.save()`, not a raw SQL "INSERT". The whole point of an ORM is never having to write plain SQL.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Thank you; I did not intend to use raw SQL; however, I wanted to import the table content (using `source`). I am not loading any data for that particular column so it was throwing an error! Thank you!

Comment: @Thuglife: for initial data, take a look at [Django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/). While you are at it, you may be interested into [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html) schema evolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`default` is not handled at the SQL level - [it's handled at the model level](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2231). Thus, a raw SQL query in your db environment would throw an error. Try this in your Django environment:

```
>> book_obj = Book('Harry Potter')
>> book_obj.save()
```

When done at the model level, the default value will be inserted into your SQL DB

Comment: Fair Kudos to @PaulaScardine for drawing up the example first in the comments.